# IE: jQuery.show() only shows element when using alert() before/after show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to add a simple 'wait box' on a javascript function, like this:

```
function caricaElenco(indice) {
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").show(); // Visualizzo 'rotella' caricamento
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").hide();
}
```

And it's working good on Firefox, but not on Internet Explorer 11, that's not showing it. The HTML is:

```
<div id="ctl00_Wait1_WaitBox" class="updateProgress">
    Attendere...<br />
    <img src="../Images/wait.gif" align="middle" />
</div>
```

The weirdest thing is that I try this, for a simple check:

```
function caricaElenco(indice) {
    (...)
    alert($("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").css('display'))
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").show(); // Visualizzo 'rotella' caricamento
    alert($("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").css('display'))
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").hide();
}
```

And it's working, I mean that it's showing the alert with 'none' and after 'block'... And it's showing the box too! But not without the alert... Why?

**UPDATE:**

Tried with `[id*="Wait1_WaitBox"]`, but it's the same. jQuery version is 1.8.2.

With

> it's working only with the alert

I mean that if I do:

```
function caricaElenco(indice) {
    (...)
    alert('whatever');
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").show(); // Visualizzo 'rotella' caricamento
    alert('whatever');
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").hide();
}
```

It's showing the box, but if I do:

```
function caricaElenco(indice) {
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").show(); // Visualizzo 'rotella' caricamento
    (...)
    $("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").hide();
}
```

It's not working (I mean not showing the 'wait box', but doing all the other stuff the function has to do in (...) correctly—load a gridview with an AJAX call) on Internet Explorer 11, in Firefox are both working. No JavaScript error.

**UPDATE 2:**
Almost entire javascript function:

```
// Fill part of gridView
function loadList(index) {
    index = parseInt(index);
    buffer = 100; // Number of rows to load
    $("[id*=divGrid]").unbind('scroll');
    $('[id*="Wait1_WaitBox"]').show(); // Show loading 'wheel' 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "PageName.aspx/webMethodName",
        data: '{id:' + $("[id*=hdnID]").val() + ', index:' + index + '}',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
        if (index == 0) {
            (...)
            $("[id*=grid] tr:last-child").remove();
            var row = "<tr class='" + response.d[index].State + "'>";
            row += "<td class="Column1"></td>";
            (...)
            row += "<td class="DateColumn"></td>";
            (...)
            row += "<td class='columnN'></td></tr>";

            $("[id*=grid]").append(row);
        }
        row = $("[id*=grid] tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("[id*=grid] tr:last-child").remove();
        if (index <= response.d.length) {
            if (index + buffer > response.d.length)
                var stop = response.d.length;
            else
                var stop = index + buffer;
            (...)
            for (var i = index; i < stop; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                (...)  
                $("td", row).eq(j).html("<span id='lblCodeNumber" + i + "' >" + response.d[i].CodeNumber + "</span>"); j++;
                (...)
                var effectDate = new Date(parseInt(response.d[i].effectDate.substr(6)));
                $("td", row).eq(j).html(effectDate.getDate() + '/' + (effectDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + effectDate.getFullYear()); j++;
                }
                (...)
                var toBeCounted = "";
                var checked = "";
                if (response.d[i].ToBeCounted != null)
                    toBeCounted = response.d[i].ToBeCounted .toString();
                else
                    toBeCounted = "true"; 
                if (toBeCounted == "true")
                    checked = "checked = 'checked'";
                else
                    checked = ""; 
                var rdToBeCounted = "<span><input type='radio' class='radio' " + checked + " name='ToBeCounted" + i + "' value='s' id='sToBeCounted" + i + "' />";
                rdToBeCounted += "<label for='s" + i + "'>YES</label>";
                if (toBeCounted == "false")
                    checked = "checked = 'checked'";
                else
                    checked = "";
                toBeCounted += "<input type='radio' class='radio' " + checked + " name='ToBeCounted" + i + "' value='n' id='nToBeCounted" + i + "' />";
                rdToBeCounted += "<label for='n" + i + "'>NO</label></span>";
                $("td", row).eq(j).html(rdToBeCounted); 
                $("[id*=grid]").append(riga);
                (...)
                riga = $("[id*=grid] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            if (stop < response.d.length) {
                $("[id*=divGrid]").scroll(function (e) {
                    if (element_in_scroll(".congruenti tbody tr:last")) {
                        loadList($(".congruenti tbody tr:last td:last").html());
                    };
                });
            }
            $('[id*="Wait1_WaitBox"]').hide();
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error! " + result.status + " - " + result.statusText);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Try:) $('[id*="Wait1_WaitBox"]')

Comment: 1st: please add the jQuery version you're using. 2nd: What do you mean with "`But not without the alert`"? Does an Javascript error occour (check your console)?

Comment: It might be a rendering bug of IE, can you please inspect the state/style of the `Wait1_WaitBox` element in the developer tools (F12)?

Comment: I could try when I come back to work on monday, but as is in the question, I've tried alert($("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").css('display')) before and after the .show(), and I get correctly 'none' and 'block'. I think too is IE rendering the problem..

Answer (score 2):

At the end you seem to be hiding it again `$("[id*=Wait1_WaitBox]").hide();`.

You need to show what goes in between these two lines.

It works with `alert` because the execution of the script is frozen until you close the alert (*and that final line is not executed yet*).

Comment: OK, I could show what goes in between in detail when I come back to work on monday. But is an ajax call to a web method that load part of a gridview with an endless scrolling effect (they don't want paging). It takes a while, with firefox showing the box while loading (also without alert), but with IE not showing nothing until gridview is loaded, and some users soon start clicking everywhere blocking the page.. Probably rendering bug of IE as try-catch-finally sayed, I was wondering if could be some workaround..

Comment: Found same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985969/how-to-show-jquery-ui-dialog-box-before-an-ajax-call

Comment: And solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816740/jquery-ui-dialog-showing-waiting-message-until-ajax-call-is-processed